# regex catching mentions

Tags: php, regex

I need to match all mentions without RT before.  I've tried adding ! to negate the rt but don't work.

```
preg_match( '/\b!rt\s*@([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20})/i', $string, $data );
```

this must match: 'hello @user how are you'.
this not: 'RT @user how are you'

Im not trying to extract usernames or something, what I need is to know if the text has @user without RT.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to match?  Just `@user`? Or the whole string.

Comment: I want to know if the text have this structure [at]user without the RT to filter it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!` doesn't "negate" in regex.  That matches a literal `!`.  What you want is a "Negative Lookbehind".

```
/(?<!RT)\s@([a-z0-9]{1,20})/i
```

`(?<!RT)` means "not preceded by "RT".

This will match the username, the "RT" isn't included as a match.

```
$match = preg_match('/(?<!RT)\s@([a-z0-9]{1,20})/i', $string);
```

If `$match` is `0`, it means the string was "RT @user ...".  If `$match` is not `0`, that means the string did *not* start with "RT @user".

DEMO: http://ideone.com/bOWbu

More info on regex lookarounds: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: @Rocket I think he wants to catch the "hello" but not the "RT". He had an old question like this and deleted it.

Comment: @Rocket I want to know if the text have this structure [at]user without the RT to filter it.

Comment: @greenbandit: I updated my answer.  After matching the regex, just check the return value of `preg_replace`.

Comment: yes, this is working. thank you, I Forgot last night finding my own answer without success. thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to match the username you can try `/(?<!RT)(@.*?)(?=\s)/i`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do it:

```
$string1 = 'hello @user how are you';
preg_match('~\s?(?<!RT) @[a-z0-9]+~i', $string1, $data);
print_r($data);
// array('0' => '@user');

$string2 = 'RT @user how are you';
preg_match('~\s?(?<!RT) @[a-zA-Z0-9]+~', $string2, $data);
print_r($data);
// empty array
```

Comment: both examples return: Array
(
    [0] =>  @user
)